# facebook getLoginUrl() not doing anything

Tags: php, facebook

Not sure what the issue is, I know FB's docs aren't very good but I got the errors to stop thanks to some sites correcting FB's mistakes. But when I put the getLoginUrl() on the page like it suggests I do I get nothing. When I say nothing I mean a blank page.

Here's the test script (with the app # and secret # removed):

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', '/facebook');
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app number', 'secret number');

// FACEBOOK LOGIN STUFF
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.prayerpond.com/index.php' );


try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?PHP echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a>'; ?>


</body>
</html>
```

If it helps, when I try to echo the results on my actual webpage I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getLoginUrl() on a non-object
> in

Now I'm getting this error all of a sudden:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with
> message 'Session not active, could not store state.' in
> /home/wiseman/public_html/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php:254
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/wiseman/public_html/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php(97):
> Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->storeState('da3d6565ec97ed5...')
>
> ## 1 /home/wiseman/public_html/test.php(77): Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getLoginUrl() #2 {main} thrown
>
> in /home/wiseman/public_html/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php
> on line 254

Comment: It looks like your `$helper` object isn't initialized correctly ... Put `echo $ex->getMessage()` in your `catch` blocks, and see if there is any errors

Comment: Add `session_start()` to the beginning of your script

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I forgot to put session_start() on my test page. Doesn't explain why I'm getting the error on my actual page, but at least it's working on the test page.